# How to disable primefaces tree with checkbox selection mode

Tags: primefaces

I have a requirement to disable a primeface tree (checkbox selection mode) for some occasions.User should be able to see selected as well as un-selected checboxes, but they need to be disabled in this occasion. Does anybody know how to do it?
Iam using PF 4

Comment: If TreeTable work for you, you can have the tree, the checkbox and a better control on this thing I think - http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/treeTableCheckbox.jsf - not sure if you can disable the checkbox easily, but I feel there's a good chance

Comment: @Leo Link leads to dead end now

Answer (score 6):

You can set for node userNode.setSelectable(false) and in jsf treetable add

```
showUnselectableCheckbox="true"
```

Answer (score 3):

I found a solution for this. But is not elegant, this can be done with css, We can add a conditional css to the tree and make it unclickable.

```
    .not-clickable {
    cursor: not-allowed;
    pointer-events: none;
}
```

Used above css style in the tree with a condition,

```
<p:tree id="tree" styleClass="#{not backingBean.editable?'not-clickable':''}" cache="false" value="#{backingBean.treeRoot}" var="node" selectionMode="checkbox" selection="#{backingBean.selectedValuesNodes}">
```

Answer (score 1):

Set Node.setSelectable(false) for the nodes whose checkboxes you want disabled.

Comment: if i choose that way, primeface removes all checkboxes and shows a plain tree. i dont want to remove checkboxes, i need to show them in disabled mode.